# Using XMLHttpRequest to read a file whose filename contains %

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to read a file called "filename%3Fformat=json".  I'm getting an error back saying zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/file%3Fformat=json 404 (Not Found).

If I change the request to "filename3Fformat=json" and change the filename to the same (basically remove the % from both the filename and the request, it works just fine ... but I need to be able to include % in the filename.

I added the setRequestHeader in desperation but that didn't seem to make any difference.

```
var requestAllStations = new XMLHttpRequest();

requestAllStations.onload = function ( ) {
    if (requestAllStations.readyState == requestAllStations.DONE && requestAllStations.status == 200) {
        // get json file content
        var allFITStations = JSON.parse(requestAllStations.responseText);

        console.log(allFITStations);
    }
};

requestAllStations.open("get", "./file%3Fformat=json", true );
requestAllStations.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
requestAllStations.send();
```

Comment: Should we assume that you have a server that is processing requests and returning responses to requests that look like: `GET /./path/to/file.html` whose payload contain the entire content of the file?

Comment: What you are describing is percent encoding - it's a way to encode special characters. You would have to percent encode the percent sign, I'll look up in a minute how to do that. It might be worth going into more detail why that character is present in the first place, though.

Comment: The correct percent encoded notation of `filename%3Fformat=json` is  `filename%253Fformat%3Djson`. There's online tools out there like http://www.url-encode-decode.com But as said maybe there is an underlying problem here that is worth treating

Comment: @Pekka웃 OP can just use the native JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent` and pass the function the name of the file instead of using some 3rd party tool.

Comment: I used encodeURIComponent to get from "file?format=json" to "file%3Fformat=json".  Initially, the = sign also got converted but that's not the way the filename got encoded so I just replace the %3D with =.  I know the filename and my request match.  Like I said, if I just take the % out of both, it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your responses.  Pekka's comment about percent encoding the percent sign was right on track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript's escape() function to encode the special characters.

```
requestAllStations.open("get", escape("./file%3Fformat=json"), true );
```

The string escaped string will look like:

```
./file%253Fformat%3Djson
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Rakesh.  You were right on track.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up adding a .replace(/%/g, "%25") to the requested filename.  I'm guessing what was happening was my server was trying to decode %3F to a ? in the filename so I'm further encoding the filename to include "%" (%25).

```
filename = file?format=json    
encodeURIComponent(filename).replace(/%3D/g, "=").replace(/%/g, "%25"))
```

Comment: The only reason I used replace rather than escape was because I wanted to preserve "=" since those were still in my filename.

Comment: You don't need to all this. Most server side languages have decode function that will give you the desired result. For example, in PHP, you could just do urldecode('./file%253Fformat%3Djson') and it will return you ./file%3Fformat=json